# How do I make the train go forward and take damage in Snowplow?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I recently played on the new 'Snowplow' map for TF2, and while it seems easy enough to make the train go forward for Blu team, I wasn't actually making it go forward myself - I assume my teammates were doing something while I was busy taking out sentry nests as a spy - so the map has left me a little confused.

Even more confusing to me was playing defense, where every 1 minute or so, the train would inexplicably take damage without any apparent input from my team at all.

What exactly makes the train go forward in Snowplow, and how does the train take damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the map name, cp_snowplow is a Control Point map.  Specifically, it's an Attack/Defend Control Points map, similar to Dustbowl.

It consists of 2 stages with 3 control points per stage.

After setup is done, there will be about 15 seconds before the train gates near BLU spawn come down and the train speeds down the track (killing everyone in its way) until it hits the first roadblock near point A.

Every 30 seconds thereafter, the train is hit by the device next to the current control point, dealing 10% damage.

Successfully capturing a point adds a percentage back to the train's health... the **problem** being that this is buggy and the exact amount added *seems* to be random between 10% and 30%.

Note: The train will not be smashed by the current trap as long as BLU is on the control point.  This acts as a sort of overtime mechanic.

Once a point is captured, the roadblock will break and the train will speed down the track until it hits the next roadblock.

Control points are somewhere near the roadblock, but they may not be immediately next to it.

TL;DR cp_snowplow is an A/D Control Point map with a fancy (and slightly broken) timer system.

Answer (score 1):

In Snowplow, the objective for team A is to get the train across the map, and team B must stop them. There are three control points that must be captured to gain clearance for the train to move forward, and upon team A's capturing of the point, it will speed towards the subsequent one. Every 30 seconds that team B defends the control point, the train will take damage (a car is seen being dropped on the train to inflict damage upon it) for 10% of its maximum 100% health.